# Make SFTP Shares Available From Sleep

Tags: server, suspend, sftp

I have looked at many posts and have not found an answer that seems applicable to my problem.  I seldom power off my desktop, I usually just put it to sleep so when I log back in it's the same state I left it.

I have another computer that I use as a file server that has sftp shares setup.  Whenever I take the desktop computer out of sleep, the files are not available unless I first access them via the file manager.  So an app like my media player will not find the library until I open the folder.

Is this an auto mount situation?  The shares seem to be mounted, just not accessible until "woken up" again.  How can I resolve this issue?  I believe it is an issue with SFTP since I was not having this problem when my previous server used Samba shares.

PS I am the only user and the user name and passwords are the same on both machines

Thanks

Comment: I'm confused about what you're asking. Are you looking for a way to wake the server up? Or are you asking how to make it work while it's asleep (impossible)

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1403116/edit) and add the exact method how you mount the `sftp` share when your desktop starts. If you have `sshfs` installed and have an entry in the file /etc/fstab` corresponding to the `sshfs` then please add that line in the question above. If you double click on a bookmark in Nautilus or use another icon (where?) to initially mount the sftp share, then indicate exactly how you do it.

Comment: If you open a terminal and enter the command `sudo mount -a` after waking up the desktop from sleep. Does it mount the sftp shared folder from the "File Server"?

Comment: Not sure how I can edit my question.  I am not waking up the server, the server is always on.
To give an example, when I wake the computer if I were to try and play something in my media player it will not play because the share is not available (all media files are on the server).  I need to go to the file manager and open the folder (share) from a bookmark. Then the files are available.  The same if I were to re-start the computer.
Mount -a does not make the shares available

Comment: You should [edit your question by clicking on the "Edit" written to the left of your name at the bottom of your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1403116/edit) or just click this link.